# two action sheet showing up when using long press

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uiactionsheet

Inside my viewDidLoad, I have the following:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longpressGesture =[[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongpressGesture:)];
longpressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 1;
longpressGesture.allowableMovement = 5;
longpressGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:longpressGesture];
[longpressGesture release];
```

I created the following:

```
-(IBAction) handleLongpressGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *) sender {

    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Delete Record?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Yes",@"No",nil];
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
    [actionSheet release];
}
```

Using the simulator, when I long press, two action sheet shows up instead of the one.

Any ideas as to why this is so?
Is it a problem with the simulator?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a problem with the simulator.

The gesture handler is called multiple times as the gesture goes through different states (began, ended, etc).

You need to check the gesture's `state` in the handler method:

```
-(IBAction) handleLongpressGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *) sender {
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] init...
        [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
        [actionSheet release];
    }
}
```